# Application of xpath to parse xml document using vba

Tags: vba, xpath, web-scraping, xml-parsing, xmldom

Today i came across a blog where I found a demo in which it was shown how to parse items applying xpath from xml document using vba. it will be just awesome if it is possible to do the same from a website.

Here is how it is done from a locally saved file:

```
Sub XML_Parsing()
    Dim xml As Object, post As Object

    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xml.async = False: xml.validateOnParse = False
    xml.Load (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\htdocs.txt")

     For Each post In xml.SelectNodes("//DistributionLists/List")
        x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = post.SelectNodes(".//Name")(0).Text
        Cells(x, 2) = post.SelectNodes(".//TO")(0).Text
        Cells(x, 3) = post.SelectNodes(".//CC")(0).Text
        Cells(x, 4) = post.SelectNodes(".//BCC")(0).Text
    Next post
End Sub
```

And the above code should be applied upon a text file named "htdocs.txt" saved in Desktop.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DistributionLists>
    <List>
        <Name>Recon</Name>
        <TO>John;Bob;Rob;Chris</TO>
        <CC>Jane;Ashley</CC>
        <BCC>Brent</BCC>
    </List>
    <List>
        <Name>Safety Metrics</Name>
        <TO>Tom;Casper</TO>
        <CC>Ashley</CC>
        <BCC>John</BCC>
    </List>
    <List>
        <Name>Performance Report</Name>
        <TO>Huck;Ashley</TO>
        <CC>Tom;Andrew</CC>
        <BCC>John;Seema</BCC>
    </List>
</DistributionLists>
```

The extracted results:

```
Recon   John;Bob;Rob;Chris  Jane;Ashley Brent
Safety Metrics  Tom;Casper  Ashley  John
Performance Report  Huck;Ashley Tom;Andrew  John;Seema
```

Now, I've got two questions:

```
1. How to parse the same from a website as i did above, as in "example.com"? If it was "html element" then i could load like "html.body.innerHTML = http.responsetext" but in this case what should be the process?
2. If i do the above thing using EARLY BINDING: what should be the reference to add to the library?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have found the solution already. Here it is:

```
Sub XML_Parsing()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim xmldoc As Object, post As Object

    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://wservice.viabicing.cat/v1/getstations.php?v=1", False
        .send
        Set xmldoc = .responseXML
        xmldoc.LoadXML .responseXML.xml
    End With

     For Each post In xmldoc.SelectNodes("//station")
        x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = post.SelectNodes(".//lat")(0).Text
        Cells(x, 2) = post.SelectNodes(".//long")(0).Text
    Next post
End Sub
```

Partial results:

```
$41.40  2.180042
41.39553    2.17706
41.393699   2.181137
41.39347    2.18149
```